# postgres: caseif value not exist sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to compute the top10 of my companies doing best Turnover. I did the code below. My problem is to get the best when if i have less than 10 companies. My query below return NULL if i have < 10 companies in my table turnover.
In case that i have only 8 companies, i want return only the top of these 8 companies. (column total).

Please tell me if im not clear!

**Code**

```
create table turnover (
id    integer,
cat     varchar(40),
date_      date,
total_     integer,
CONSTRAINT turnover_ UNIQUE(id, cat, date_));

create table contact (
id    integer,
date_     date,
Type_      varchar(40),
total_      integer,
CONSTRAINT cnt UNIQUE(id, date_, type_)); 
select
id, cat, t_date, total_, c_date, type_, total_
from
(
    select 
   t.id, t.cat, t.date_ "t_date",  t.total_,
   c.date_ "c_date", c.type_, c.total_
   count(*) over (partition by t.date_) as cnt,
   row_number() over (partition by t1.date_ order by t.total_ desc) as rn
    from turnover t
 inner join contact c on t.id = c.id
 where t.cat = 'cat1' and t.total_ > 0
 ) t1
 where t1.rn/t1.cnt<=0.10
```

Comment: Seems your query is not properly built, syntactical errors are there. You can put a LIMIT at the end of SQL Query. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your example:

```
 where (t1.rn - 1) < 0.10 * t1.cnt
```

But this is probably a better approximation:

```
 where t1.rn = 1 or
       t1.rn <= 0.1 * t1.cnt
```

This guarantees that at least one row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    id, 
    cat, 
    t1.t_date, 
    t1.total_, 
    c_date, 
    type_, 
    total_
from
(
   select 
       t.id, 
       t.cat, 
       t.date_ "t_date", 
       t.total_ as ttotal,
       c.date_ "c_date", 
       c.type_,
       c.total_,
       count(*) over (partition by t.date_) as cnt,
       row_number() over (partition by t.date_ order by t.total_ desc) as rn
   from turnover t
 inner join contact c on t.id = c.id
 --where t.cat = 'cat1' and t.total_ > 0
 ) t1
 limit 1
```